# Is there anyway to know Aura Component run in Lightning App Builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-app-builder

I create an aura component which can used in Lightning App Builder. I want to implement this feature: when in Lightning App Builder just show diagram.

So I want to ask about is there anyway to know aura component run under Lightning App Builder or not?

In this Aura Component, I used follow method to check if Aura Component run under Lightning App Builder or not, is this a correct way?

```
var inLightningAppBuilder = window.location.href.indexOf('flexipageEditor/surface.app?') >= 0;
```

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: Sorry for replied late. My company product want to our aura component show different style in Lightning App Builder. I found an idea to check by using follow code: 
"var inLightningAppBuilder = window.location.href.indexOf('flexipageEditor/surface.app?') >= 0;" 

But we don't if this a good idea or not.

Comment: There is no supported way to do this. Components shouldn't know what context they render in, they should behave appropriately based on the data/capabilities that are available.

Comment: Thanks for your replied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like no supported way in salesforce to do this.